# Long text overflow to next component in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

When there is `max-width` set, a long sentence will be wrapped into multiple lines when the max width was hit. However, somehow the wrapped lines will overlap with the component below. For example,

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 50em;
}

div.main {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  box-shadow: grey 0px 0px 5px;
}

div.inner {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

p.footer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 8pt;
}

div.right {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

div.left {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 0px;
  max-width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="left">left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left </div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="footer"> test content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

will generate [image: this page].
However, after reducing the page width, it will be something like [image: this]
, where the overflowed left component collapsed with the footer (and maybe `inner`). Is there a way I could fix this? Thanks!

[Someone suggested `clearfix` but I have no idea how that works]

Comment: overflow:auto to inner

Comment: If a solid overview of overflow would be useful to you, I found MDN's helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Overflowing_content

Comment: @TemaniAfif for which?